# Image Sharing using XMPP framework in iOS

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I was looking for image sharing using XMPP framework. The little research I have done, describes that first I need to upload that image to the server and the corresponding link for that image will be received which can be later used to sent the image in the form of link to the XMPP server. Any other way out other than this in which I can directly sent the image to the XMPP server will be helpful.

Comment: Try this http://kashiftriffort.wordpress.com/2014/05/13/xmpp-how-to-send-message-with-image-using-xmpp-in-iphone/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `XEP-0096 (XMPPSIFileTransfer)` and `XEP-0065(TURNSocket)` together to achieve the file transfer.

Comment: SIFileTransfer works only if the receiver is online as well, Instead we worked around a way to send images and videos.